# Why do regular form submits POSTing data result in page refreshes?

Tags: html, http

Title question asks it all, what's the process going on under there? Why do I have to use AJAX if I wanted to submit that form asynchrously?

Comment: Because AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML? And because at the time forms were introduced - only server-side pages, that require page refresh anyway, were in wide use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the way HTTP was designed. Back then, JavaScript was not as ubiquitous and not as powerful as it is today.

As it is, when you POST data to a page (a path), you are issuing a request to a server. The server can then respond in a variety of manners. There is the simple "return some content", whether it be HTML, text, JSON, XML, etc. There is also the possibility for the server to return a redirect, sending you to a different location.

What AJAX does is simply to run this request in the background and hide the fact that data was submitted to the server and a response was returned from the user's perspective.